# Dynamically generated input name in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, concatenation

I am trying to make a page where users can add as many rows to a table as they want, and then the values of the inputs (there is an input in each cell of the table) are passed back to the page.

My problem comes when trying to make the name of each dynamically generated input box different.  I've tried to create a variable to do it, but the syntax I'm using, which works in other places, doesn't seem to work when creating new elements.

Here is the code in question:

```
    if ($_POST['dept_1'] != null){  //If there was an input
    $i = intval($_POST['num_of_rows']);
    while ($i != 0){
        $dept = $_POST['dept_' . $i];
        $hours = $_POST['hours_' . $i];
        echo $dept . " " . $hours . "\n";
        $i--;
    }
}
```

.....

```
var i = 2;
        $("document").ready(function(){
            $("#newrow").click(function(e){
                $("#maintable").append('<tr> \
                                        <td><input type="text" name="dept_" + i size="5" maxlength="5" /></td> \
                                        <td><input type="text" name="hours_" + i size="5" maxlength="1" /></td> \
                                    </tr>');
                                    alert("dept_" + i);
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#hiddenvalue").attr("value", "" + i + "");
                i = i + 1;
            });
        });
```

$*POST['dept*' . $i] works when $i = 1, because dept_1 is written into the HTML of the page.

alert("dept_" + i) works, concatenating the value of i to the string.

name="dept_" + i does not work.  Inspecting the new element, its name is "dept_ + i"

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution would be using an array by naming the element `dept[]`; that will give you an array `$_POST['dept']` on the PHP side.

Besides that, syntax highlighting already shows you the problem: Your `+i` is inside the string; use this instead:

```
$("#maintable").append('<tr> \
    <td><input type="text" name="dept_' + i + '" size="5" maxlength="5" /></td> \
    <td><input type="text" name="hours_' + i + '" size="5" maxlength="1" /></td> \
  </tr>');
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't make it so hard on yourself.
Use an array name.

```
<td><input type="text" name="dept[]" size="5" maxlength="5" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="hours[]" size="5" maxlength="1" /></td>
```

Get the values in PHP using $_POST['dept'] and $_POST['hours'] which will return nice clean arrays.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new.  I'm really interested in learning the answer to my question though, because I've tried to do similar things other times and had them not work.

Comment: @AndrewLatham You've got it all in ThiefMaster's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix some javascript syntax errors in your string like this so that you end the string in the appropriate places so you have `'string1' + i + 'string2'`:

```
    var i = 2;
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("#newrow").click(function(e){
            $("#maintable").append('<tr> \
                                    <td><input type="text" name="dept_' + i + '" size="5" maxlength="5" /></td> \
                                    <td><input type="text" name="hours_' + i + '" size="5" maxlength="1" /></td> \
                                </tr>');
                                alert("dept_" + i);
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#hiddenvalue").attr("value", "" + i + "");
            i = i + 1;
        });
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the result is `... name="dept_" i size="5" ...`

Comment: @AndrewLatham - I just made a correction to my answer, but even what I had before wasn't giving what you think it was.  I don't think you had the right code from my answer.  This will give `name="dept_2" size="5"`...